# Rank of a special matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, nilpotence

If a specific $n$ by $n$ matrix A satisfies the relation that $$A^n=0$$

What information can we get about its rank?

Update: Certainly it is not full rank, but can we dig more out of it?

Comment: Certainly $A$ cannot be full rank, because then $A^n$ will also have to be full rank, hence injective/surjective (which it is not, if it is the zero map). You can construct examples of any rank $<n$ to show that nothing more can be said (is the dimension also $n$? This is not specified, I have assumed it).

Answer (score 0):

aCTOH's brief comment gives the answer without getting into how. Here is a description.

Take the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Now remove its last column and as replacement put the zero vector, but as the first column. Call this matrix $A_1$.

For any $k<n$ remove the last $k$ columns from $I_n$ and replace them by equal number of zero vectors, but at the front. Call this matrix $A_k$

Note that for all these matrices the rank is the number of non-zero columns, and compute the powers for all these matrices.